# Analyze and measure technical quality in R code: any tool similar to SonarQube?

Tags: r, sonarqube

A simple question: does anybody knows if a tool similar to sonarqube exists for R code? or a sonarqube library?
I mean, a tool for analyzing technically quality of the code, not only highlighting or sintax formating.
thanks in advance!

Comment: To assess the quality of my code I personally use [testthat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/index.html) and [lintr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lintr/index.html). However `testthat` helps performing unit testing and `lintr` actually "checks adherence to a given style, syntax errors and possible semantic issues".

Comment: If you put the code in a package `R CMD check ...` will give various errors, warnings and notes.  To get onto CRAN packages must pass this without any of those.

Comment: I just found this https://github.com/Merck/sonar-r-plugin a plugin to use lintr result in sonarqube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lintr` and upload the results to **SonarQube**.  There is an example at here:

- https://github.com/paulospx/sonarqube-r

Comment: I went through this repository. this is more like a hack to upload to sonarqube but it wont assess the issue type (BUG, VULNERABILITY, CODE_SMELL) or severity (BLOCKER, CRITICAL, MAJOR, MINOR, INFO) of the code. It generates a JSON output and we need to update these fields manually.

Answer (score 0):

Another plugin for that:
https://github.com/Merck/sonar-r-plugin

Would be nice to have a native support of course.